# PHP files will not stop opening locally

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I am not sure what is going on here but I was working on configuring my apache server today but after a load of hassle gave up and just installed MAMP instead. Problem is that now when I open a local php file as soon as it opens another one opens until I close Firefox. When I open the file with Chrome all that is displayed is code? A page is fine until I change the extension from .html to .php

It makes no difference where the file is located (ie local host or desktop).
Has anyone else had this problem? I suspect it may be something to do with installing apache manually and then MAMP? Something must have gone wrong along the way.

Perhaps it is possible to completely uninstall apache and start again, but I have no idea how to do this!

Thank you for any help,

Margate

Comment: any way. If the rest of the site is open I click a link to a php page. Or if I just double click the .php file to open it with my default browser (Firefox). If it opens it is a problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubling clicking PHP files in a File Explorer type thing or opening from the file system with the Open dialog of a browser will open them as regular HTML or Text (depending on the browser).  To get them to work as PHP you have to go as if to a webpage, since PHP code is interpreted by the webserver not the browser.  I.e. `http://localhost/somefile.php`

And make sure links to PHP pages in your site are relative links.  I.e. `<a href='/somefile.php'>Somefile</a>` and not file system links, i.e. `<a href='file:///c:\webroot\somefile.php'>Somefile</a>`.  PHP has to go through the server.  The same goes for HTML files too.  If you serve filesystem links, the links will not work for anyone else anyway.

Comment: Hmm, I think you may be right? I'm just testing it now! I will write back in a couple of minutes...

Comment: He is right! Thank you very much developerwjk :  ) I have done 2 php courses and the second one took me around 3 months to complete. I now think I did not learn a thing! I have spent literally hours messing around with this today trying to figure it out prior to posting on here!

Comment: Thank you developwrwjk, I will make sure to double check that my links are not pointing locally. I understand what your saying and may well have overlooked updating that prior to launch! Would have probably been back on here again asking why my links are not working!